# Trouble returning value of nested function using an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to append the results from an ajax call to a paragraph using jQuery.

I would like to return the variable "myResult" from the inner getResult function and pass it to the outer buildParagraph function, but the value returned is `undefined`.

How do I append the value of myResults to the `<p>` tag as indicated below?

```
function buildParagraph () {

   function getResult(url) {  
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
         var myResult = data.results;
         return myResult;
      } 
   }

  var myUrl = 'www.mywebsite.com';

  getResult(myUrl);

  $('<p>').html(myResult);

}
```

Comment: You can not return data from asynchronous methods..Use callbacks instead...

Comment: Just move the instantiation of myResult into  buildParagraph. As stated above no need to return in the response handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a callback function inside ajax success,Or the easiest way is move the below code to the ajax success function

```
$('<p>').html(data.results);
```